# ClassNotFoundException in Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, osgi

I'm writing an Eclipse plugin that uses class org.eclipse.team.svn.core.utility.SVNUtility from plugin 'org.eclipse.team.svn.core'.

I've specified the plugin in my Require-Bundle header and imported the package:

```
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.team.svn.core
Import-Package: org.eclipse.team.svn.core.utility
```

and also checked that the package is exported by the svn plugin. But when the class is referenced in a handler of my plugin, I get

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.team.svn.core.utility.SVNUtility cannot be found by my.plugin.id_1.0.0.qualifier
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you running this using Run > Eclipse Application in Eclipse?

Comment: You don't need to do both Require-Bundle and Import-Package. It's one or the other.

Comment: @greg-449 I'm actually deploying and running Eclipse with my plugin using IntelliJ IDEA, but I'm not sure if that matters

Comment: @KonstantinKomissarchik, I've tried leaving one of those, I still get ClassNotFoundException

Comment: `org.eclipse.team.svn.core` is not part of the core Eclipse so is it actually installed?

Comment: @greg-449, yes, the whole set of SVN team provider plugins are installed and working

Comment: I have not heard of IntelliJ having Eclipse/OSGi authoring facilities. I would guess that it's not setting up and launching your runtime environment correctly.

Comment: @KonstantinKomissarchik, have you heard of manually editing the MANIFEST.MF and plugin.xml? ;)

Comment: Yes, you can manually edit your source files, but do you have the infrastructure in place to correctly provision the plugin into your target environment and then correctly launch said environment?

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with what you're doing (except that the Require-Bundle header is redundant and should be removed). Are you absolutely sure the exported package actually contains the `SVNUtility` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, that turned out to be pretty stupid one — `-clean` did the trick